# ZAP-Form based Authentication not working -How to scan a web pages by providing username/password directly on web page

Tags: zap

How to scan web pages for site where we need to do login with username/Password.
I used form based authentication but its not working as I am getting POST response as follows.so please let me know how I can scan by providing credentials manually. Thanks!

**POST response:**
message=%7B%22actions%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22114%3Ba%22%2C%22descriptor%22%3A%22apex%3A%2F%2Fapplauncher.LoginFormController%2FACTION%24login%22%2C%22callingDescriptor%22%3A%22markup%3A%2F%2FsalesforceIdentity%3AloginForm2%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22username%22%3A%22ZAP%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22ZAP%22%2C%22startUrl%22%3A%22%2Femployee%2Fs%2F%22%7D%2C%22version%22%3A%2250.0%22%7D%5D%7D&aura.context=%7B%22mode%22%3A%22PROD%22%2C%22fwuid%22%3A%22r9KGPExoo3AsD7hYz77h_Q%22%2C%22app%22%3A%22siteforce%3AloginApp2%22%2C%22loaded%22%3A%7B%22APPLICATION%40markup%3A%2F%2Fsiteforce%3AloginApp2%22%3A%22vnhBtFVfVynX5gzVl_c_-A%22%7D%2C%22dn%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22globals%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22uad%22%3Afalse%7D&aura.pageURI=%2Femployee%2Fs%2Flogin%2F%3Fec%3D302%26startURL%3D%252Femployee%252Fs%252F&aura.token=undefined

Answer (score 1):

For info this question has already been asked on the ZAP User Group: https://groups.google.com/g/zaproxy-users/c/W55XLZe3lOY/m/KLAa_nRmCAAJ
Thats were I'm going to follow up on it :)